# Low graphics mode Hybrid Graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

My Ubuntu version is 14.04 4.4.0-81-generic, laptop is Dell Inspiron 3558 with Nvidia video card GeForce-920M and integrated Intel HDGraphics. I have spent a huge amount of time trying to find a way to switch between graphic cards.

I tried installing Bumblebee and different (suggested by ppa:graphics repository (390, 384 and 387 versions)) Nvidia drivers and everytime it ends up with "low graphics mode" screen when I switch to Nvidia card.

By the way, binary Nvidia drivers gave black screen while installing drivers from `*.run` source files from Nvidia website Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop (i.e. when I log in, then it logs out immediately). I haven't found an appropriate solution of my issue on the Internet.

What else can I do?

Comment: Why are you using a 4 years old release?

Comment: Because I use ROS Indigo which is compatible only with 14.04

Comment: And why are you using Indigo when you could be using Lunar? Just a curiosity because you aren't the first one in that self-inflicted catch22. What's so special about the Indigo release?

Comment: I have just started completing my bachelor's degree and previous part of project is using ROS Indigo.  I didn't try to build driver packages on later distributions of ROS: maybe they won't even be built.

Comment: Not really. It's supposed to be compatible. Besides, Indigo has problems of its own with just normal updates within 14.04: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1

Comment: This problems may occur only in case of installing this packages because of unresolved dependencies during ROS installation, isn't it? If everything was installed fine then this warning means nothing for people who successfully installed ROS. ROS Indigo is oficially compatible only with Trusty, otherwise errors are expected: https://answers.ros.org/question/226098/ros-on-ubuntu-xenial-1604/

Comment: My point is errors are expected even with 14.04 depending on the kernel branch. Besides, support for both Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo will end in April 2019.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful link where driver's versions with graphics cards are written which I occationnally found on the Internet

https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142
(Support timeframes for Unix legacy GPU releases)

The only key to solve this issue was to find and install an appropriate driver(I have understood this because previously I found good nvidia-361 driver and one day it didn't work(maybe after updating ) so I removed it) Using this link, I realised that for my videocard nvidia-340 driver is recommended. However, this wasn't mentioned in additional drivers application or using command:

> sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

So I just typed

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-340

and everything became fine( now I am able to switch between graphic cards )!!